# build ok but deploy won't work / Heroku & gitlab

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js, gitlab-ci

I want to deploy a discord bot on heroku, but when I try to deploy it, he don't want to work. My code for my .gitlab-ci.yml is that :

```
image: node:latest

cache:
  paths:
  - node_modules/

job:
  script:
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y ruby ruby-dev rubygems-integration
  - npm install
  - gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri dpl
  - dpl --provider=heroku --app=APP NAME ON HEROKU --api-key=MY API KEY ON HEROKU
# change app name and api key if necessary
```

I hope you can help me to solve my problem.

PS: I don't share my APP NAME ON HEROKU and my API KEY ON HEROKU because it's for more security.

Comment: Hey there, I myself am little confused? How it does not work? What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Hello, 

It not work. The error I get is that :

`npm ERR! path /builds/Yotlan/bot-one-piece-luffy/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/builds/Yotlan/bot-one-piece-luffy/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent`

I hope you can help me @Patrik :'(

Comment: Can you update your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to add a `ls` before the `npm install` line to see if there's a `package.json` file present in the root directory? There has to be a `package.json` file for `npm install` to run.